# Replacement for InteractionType in DIscord.py COmponents

Tags: button, pagination, discord, discord.py

I just saw that discord components removed the `InteractionType` and now my pagination doesn't work anymore... I don't know what to do so if you could help me replace it and explain me how the replacement of it works so that I can do it also! BTW here's the code! Thanks!

```py
await interaction.respond(
    type = InteractionType.UpdateMessage,
    embed = paginationList[current],
    components = [
        [
            Button(
                label = "Prev",
                id = "back",
                style = ButtonStyle.blue
            ),
            Button(
                label = f"Page {int(paginationList.index(paginationList[current])) + 1}/{len(paginationList)}",
                id = "cur",
                style = ButtonStyle.grey,
                disabled = True
            ),
            Button(
                label = "Next",
                id = "front",
                style = ButtonStyle.blue
            )
        ]
    ]
)
```